# Conditional image width - responsive

Tags: html, css

I currently am happy with my image size on a desktop. It's set to 50%. But when I view the image on my phone, it's way too small. I'm wondering how do I set image to be 100% if it's on a mobile device but 50% on desktop.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxLvEQ

```
<img class="featuredImg" src="http://bandwagonbible.azurewebsites.net/Stories/NFLBeginnersGuide/Image1.JPG" width="50%"/>
```

I've tried this method but specifying px I think isn't really idea.

```
img
{
    max-width: 50%;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: please clear css in the link !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use media query for device like,

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    img { width:100%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to set the min-width and max-width of viewport.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 768px)
```

And underneath it you can write code that you wanna to be applied when the viewport is between 300 and 768 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

change "%" to "vw" :

```
img
{
max-width: 50vw;//or 100vw depends on you
}
```

because when we uses "%" instead vw means % of parent element width

 maybe parent have 100px of width so 50% of width for child is 50px
also define a viewport :

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```